# How to detect if a Windows installation is RTL

Tags: windows, winapi, right-to-left

(I'm using Windows XP, but the question is relevant to all/any Windows version)

Windows setup comes in 2 "flavoers": LTR or RTL.
meaning, the GUI (buttons, windows' controls, menus, and more) is displayed from left to right, or from left to right.

This is relevant mostly to Hebrew and Arabic versions of Windows.

My program needs to find out the default behavior of displaying its widgets.

The LOCALE is not the right answer!

Local pertains to date format, thousands separator, UI language, and other language/culture specific settings, but in Windows, locale doesn't affect the UI direction.

How can I find out (registry, env, etc) the OS's direction?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/22/10250164.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant isn't that only for a given locale?

Comment: Sure, like the system locale.

Comment: Note that Windows Viata+ don't have specific LTR and RTL version, it all depends on the current language pack and locale.

Comment: Just display your application's UI in the direction it was designed. There's no point trying to display English text in RTL just because you're on an RTL system.

Answer (score 3):

[`BOOL GetProcessDefaultLayout(DWORD *pdwDefaultLayout)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
or
`DWORD GetLayout(HDC hdc)`

Answer (score 2):

Check for [`WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms903932.aspx) with `GetWindowLong` on the system taskbar to find out where the start menu is positioned, which will give you the OS text direction:

```
if (GetWindowLong(FindWindow(_T("HHTaskBar"), NULL), GWL_EXSTYLE) != 0)
    //it's RTL
```

Comment: `Shell_TrayWnd` is another option.

Answer (score -1):

How about using GetSystemMetrics with nIndex of SM_MIDEASTENABLED, it will return nonzero if the system is enabled for Hebrew and Arabic, 0 if not.

Comment: No. This just means that i can read & write properly. it doesn't say anything about the GUI direction. My system has LTR GUI, and "your" function returns 1 (True).